# express, creating cookie with json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, cookies, express

i'm using express 3.x and trying to create a cookie.

i'm trying following json:

```
res.cookie('cart', {
                styles: styles[product],
                count: 0,
                total: 0
            })
```

where product is:

```
{product: {
       "_id": style._id,
       "style": style.style,
       "a": style.a,
       "color": color,
       "price": style.price,
       "desc": style.desc,
       "img": style.img,
       "category": style.category,
       "quantity": 1
        }
```

}

and

```
var product = req.params.a + "_" + style.id;
```

i can't make 'styles[product]' to work. what's my problem??

i need to create a json that looks like 'req.cookies.cart.styles[product]' this

please help!

Answer (score 4):

You can only store a string value in cookie. Let's take a situation that you want to store a boolean true in a cookie, It is converted into a string "true" and stored in browser cookie. Following code will do the same

```
res.cookie('myBoolean', true)
```

Now boolean true stored as string "true" in cookie.

In your case you trying to store an object in cookie. So internally your object converted into string by calling function like follows

```
var myObj = {name: 'myObj'}
myObj.toString()
```

Exactly In your code, the cookie consist value

```
res.cookie('cart', ({
                styles: styles[product],
                count: 0,
                total: 0
            }).toString())
```

You can check browser and you can see the cookie as follows

```
cart:[object Object]
```

So the better idea is, You have to use JSON.stringify/JSON.parse as follows

**Set Cookie:**

res.cookie('cart', JSON.stringify({
    styles : styles[product],
    count : 0,
    total : 0
}))

**Get Cookie**

```
var cookieData = JSON.parse(req.cookies.cart)
```

**Note:** However you can store cookie by using JSON.stringify, store such a cart information is not advisable. You have to prefer session storage instead of cookie.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know cookie only store a string. I tried with session but it eats too much memories so that chrome stores eight styles in cart and internet explorer stores ten styles.. so I was exploring for alternative

Comment: @wisleans, You can store session in memcache or database. It is very optimistic solution when you run node app with load balancing. connect-memcached, connect-mongo, session-mongoose modules and more are there. you can try any of these.

Comment: which module do you prefer? connect-memcached seems very complicated.. connect-mongo is giving me an error saying socket hang up.

Comment: @wisleans, I have used session-mongoose in one of my production. This is powerful session management module with mongoDB's replica set. You can try this

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are usually transmitted in this format:

```
"var1=value1;var2=value2;"
```

instead of

```
{"var1": "value1"; "var2": "value2"}
```

---

I had a similar problem - I needed to convert a JSON object to a cookie, and I was able to solve it by converting this object to a string, and then replacing some key syntax elements:

```
var req_options = {
    headers: {
        // ...
        'Cookie': JSON.stringify(
            {"var1": "value", "var2": "value2"}
            ).replace(":", "=").replace(/\{|\}|\"/g, "").replace(",", ";")
    }
};
```

In my case, the full version of the working code looks something like this:

```
const request = require('request');

var req_options = {
    uri: '...',
    headers: {
        //'Accept': 'text/html', 'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)',
        'Cookie': JSON.stringify(
            {"var1": "value", "var2": "value2"}
            ).replace(":", "=").replace(/\{|\}|\"/g, "").replace(",", ";")
    }
};

function doRequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        process.stdout.write("Calling for " + req_options.uri + "... ");
        request(req_options, function (error, res, body) {
            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log("200 OK, answer:\n", JSON.parse(body)); //resolve("200 OK");
            }
            if (error)
                return reject(error);
        });
    });
}

async function mainLoop() {
    console.clear();
    console.log("Hi");
    console.log("headers.cookie: \"" + req_options.headers.Cookie + "\"");
    await doRequest().then(function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
    console.log("Bye");
}

mainLoop();
```

---

In your case, it might look something like this:

```
res.cookie('cart',
    JSON.stringify({
        styles: styles[product],
        count: 0,
        total: 0
    }).replace(":", "=").replace(/\{|\}|\"/g, "").replace(",", ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what you want to achieve. If `product` is really the object then it hardly can be used as a key - it will be converted to the `[object Object]` string and `styles[product]` will be equal to `styles['[object Object]']`.

If `styles[product]` returns the product like one that is in the second code block, then `style.id` probably should be `style.product._id`.

The best I can suggest is to check all the intermediate steps by adding `console.log`. For example:

```
console.log('keys of styles:', Object.keys(styles));
console.log('product:', product);
res.cookie('cart', {
    styles: styles[product],
    count: 0,
    total: 0
})
```

This will show you what exactly is added to the cookie. Use the similar approach to test other parts of the algorithm.